# Error translating mvel script to groovy

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, mvel

While preparing for an update to elasticsearch 2.0, I noticed mvel scripting is being deprecated in favor of groovy. My problem is that I am new to groovy and don't know how to fix this error.

```
boolean engineTest = false; if (!engineTest) { engineTest = true;} return engineTest;
```

This throws the following error

```
unexpected token: return @ line 1, column 68. [...]
```

Comment: why don't you just return true ?

Comment: this is not the full code ;)

Comment: Maybe a better example next time? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it all needs to be on 1 line, then you're missing a semi-colon before the return statement. As in:

```
​boolean engineTest = false; if (!engineTest) { engineTest = true}; return engineTest;​
```

Otherwise, you could split the statements on 3 lines and avoid all semi-colons.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize my code was executing inline!